# StorageFolder.GetFilesAsync() is not working in HoloLens 2 (ARM64)

Tags: uwp, hololens, storagefolder

I have a problem specific to Windows.Storage build for HoloLens 2 (ARM64). Tested on HoloLens 1 (x86) with no sight of any kind of problems.

Here is the problem: The GetFilesAsync method returns an empty collection without considering the presence of files in the specified 'KnownFolders' directory. The same is for the method GetItemsAsync (not tested for folders).

When the method GetFileAsync() was used to load an existing file in the same 'KnownFolders' directory the result was correct.

Configuration:

- UWP Visual Studio template.
- Target version 1903, Build 18362.
- HoloLens 2 device
- Device windows version 10.0.19041.1136.

Here is a reprex:

```
    private async Task<string[]> GetNames()
    {
        StorageFolder storageFolder = KnownFolders.Objects3D;
        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await storageFolder.GetFilesAsync();

        string[] names = files.Select(f => f.Name).ToArray();

        return names;
    }
```

Thank you for any suggestions in advance.

Comment: We cannot reproduce issue here and works on real HoloLens2 device(Target version 2004, build 10.0.19041.1140, [HoloLens 2 release notes | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-release-notes#windows-holographic-version-20h2---march-2021-update)). Could you provide an MVCE(stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so that we can locate the issue?

Comment: Hi Hernando! Thank you for your time, and for the test that you did. I added a reproducible example in the post. Additionally, I'll make a test with a different target version from version 1903.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We reproduced this issue when accessed the Object3D folder and we think it is due to not really expecting to have some non-model file types in the Object3D folder for HoloLens OS. We do have a solution thought that gets a query result object that contains the files which meet the criteria in the current folder and calls the GetFilesAsync method of the query result to get the flat list of files. Here is the answer:

```
        StorageFolder objects3DFolder = KnownFolders.Objects3D;

        // Set query options with filter and sort order for results
        List<string> fileTypeFilter = new List<string>();
        // Determines which file types to include in query results.
        fileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");

        var queryOptions = new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName, fileTypeFilter);
        var query = KnownFolders.Objects3D.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);

        var files = await query.GetFilesAsync(); 

        Debug.WriteLine($"The count of collection is via files.Count :{files.Count}");
        StorageFile file = await objects3DFolder.GetFileAsync("bb.txt");
        if (file!=null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine($"Find the specified file {file.Name} successfully");
        }
```

Comment: Just in addition. The folder is going to be used for containing .glb model files.